# Trying to create a "who is it" game in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to create a "Who Is It" quiz in Android Studio. It is 5 questions - each containing a image with 4 buttons that have possible answers on then. I'm having a hard time understanding how to go about setting up the string of answers to appear on the buttons. All 4 buttons have to change once the next button is clicked. Any ideas or is this too vague? (Sorry but I'm a newbie).

Comment: Will a normal array of strings not work for holding your answers?

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about it. I have the buttons made but if let's say the first button was called btn1, do I create a string like "public static String[] btn1 = {"xxx", "yyy", "aaa", "bbb"}. Then do it for the other buttons also?

Comment: You should probably separate them by question before separating them by by button. Say like an `ArrayList` that is 5 elements long with each element holding another array that has the values for the buttons that go with the question.

Comment: Ok so something like this: public class QuizQuestion{  public static String[] q1={"xxx", "yyy"... Making a list of the 5 questions containing what the 4 buttons would contain?

Comment: Yeah something like that would work.

Comment: No Problem, consider righting what you get working as an answer to your question.